# Oracle Apex - Separating rows of card text by a line or color

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, apex

I would like to seperate the rows of the card text by a line or a different color, like it is displayed with the card title (crossed out) which has a darker grey tone than the card text.
In detail I would like to separate the first row ("Veränderung zum Vormonat:0") from the second and third row ("Ist" and "Soll"). Maybe there is a way to separate it the same way as the card title from the card text or e.g. through a solid line.
In order to edit the card I use sql in Oracle Apex (Application Express 20.1.0.00.13).

[image]

Comment: Please provide more detail. What is the region type - is this a list or a card region ? You've asked similar questions before but never provided this information. Hard to help you if you just ask the question and then never reply back to followup questions.

Comment: Hi Koen, sorry I am new to the whole system. Where do I find the region type?

Comment: Open the component (probably a report) in the page builder. The 2nd attribute in section "Identification" is called "Type". Possible values are "Breadcrumb", "Calendar", etc. I'm guessing this is type "Cards" but you have never confirmed that. If it is "Cards", then pls add where you're rendering those lines (body/secondary body ?) and post the actual you used. Please update your question with this information.